# flink count distinct issue

Tags: apache-flink, flink-cep, flink-sql

Now we use tumbling window to count distinct. The issue we have is if we extend our tumbling window from day to month, We can't have the number as of now distinct count. That means if we set the tumbling window as 1 month, the number we get is from every 1st of each month. How can I get the current distinct count for now(Now is Mar 9.)?

```
package flink.trigger;

import org.apache.flink.api.common.state.ReducingState;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.state.ReducingStateDescriptor;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.LongSerializer;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.triggers.Trigger;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.triggers.TriggerResult;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.windows.TimeWindow;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class CustomCountDistinctTigger extends Trigger<Object, TimeWindow> {

    private final ReducingStateDescriptor<Long> timeState =
            new ReducingStateDescriptor<>("fire-interval", new DistinctCountAggregateFunction(), LongSerializer.INSTANCE);
    private long interval;


    public CustomCountDistinctTigger(long interval) {
        this.interval = interval;
    }

    @Override
    public TriggerResult onElement(Object element, long timestamp, TimeWindow window, TriggerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        ReducingState<Long> fireTimestamp = ctx.getPartitionedState(timeState);

        timestamp = ctx.getCurrentProcessingTime();

        if (fireTimestamp.get() == null) {
            long start = timestamp - (timestamp % interval);
            long nextFireTimestamp = start + interval;
            ctx.registerProcessingTimeTimer(nextFireTimestamp);
            fireTimestamp.add(nextFireTimestamp);
            return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
        }
        return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public TriggerResult onProcessingTime(long time, TimeWindow window, TriggerContext ctx) throws Exception {
//        System.out.println("onProcessingTime called at "+System.currentTimeMillis() );
//        return TriggerResult.FIRE_AND_PURGE;
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        System.out.println(df.format(new Date()));
        //interval
        ReducingState<Long> fireTimestamp = ctx.getPartitionedState(timeState);

        if(window.maxTimestamp() == time) {
            return TriggerResult.FIRE_AND_PURGE;
        }
        else if (fireTimestamp.get().equals(time)) {
            fireTimestamp.clear();
            fireTimestamp.add(time + interval);
            ctx.registerProcessingTimeTimer(time + interval);
            return TriggerResult.FIRE;
        }
        return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public TriggerResult onEventTime(long time, TimeWindow window, TriggerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear(TimeWindow window, TriggerContext ctx) throws Exception {

    }

}


distinct count:
DataStreamSink<Tuple2<String, Integer>> finalResultStream = keyedStream
                            .flatMap(new KPIDistinctDataFlatMapFunction(inputSchema))
                            .map(new SwapMap())
                            .keyBy(new WordKeySelector())
                            .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time.minutes(5)))
                            .trigger(new CustomCountDistinctTigger(1 * 60 * 6000))
                            .aggregate(new DistinctCountAggregateFunction())
                            .print("final print");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a custom Trigger that returns FIRE once a day to trigger intermediate results, and then does a FIRE_AND_PURGE at the end of the month to close the window.

Every time the Trigger returns FIRE your window is evaluated by calling the `process()` method of your `ProcessWindowFunction`, at which point it can produce results with the `Collector` that is provided. FIRE_AND_PURGE evaluates the window one last time, and then destroys it.

See also the answers to this question -- [How to display intermediate results in a windowed streaming-etl?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59857255/2000823) -- which covered a related topic.

Comment: We still have problem on your solution. Can you please have a check with my question above? we are using table window to handle the count distinct. You solution the trigger is from StreamExecutionEnvironment which can have a trigger. but StreamTableEnvironment don't have trigger. Right?

Comment: I don't see a solution using the Table API or SQL.

Comment: Hi David I got an issue while I implement the custom trigger. While there is no event coming from kafka. it will not trigger the distinctcount? This code example above is for window 5 mins and every minutes to trigger distinct count.

Comment: There are no empty windows in Flink. A window is instantiated when the first event is assigned to it. So, no events, no window. No window, no trigger. No trigger, no results stating that the window was empty.

Comment: ok. So I can make the state for the intermediate result. How can I get the intermediate result on timer(for example daily) if there is no trigge fired?

Comment: I got it we need to make the query the state when you need.https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/queryable_state.html.

Comment: Once your month-long window and associated trigger have been created, the trigger's daily processing time timers will be called regardless. Doesn't matter if there have been any further events. I wouldn't use queryable state unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Hi David, Just last quetion about this topic. I found Time only support day which is the longest range. If I want to support year, What Shall I do? put the parameter as 365? If I put 365 it is not yearly aggregate actually. .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time.days(1)))