# Flink Streaming - 10 days event time window which triggers every day

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming, eventtrigger

I'm trying to aggregate data monthly (using TumblingEventTimeWindows) but i want to have the output updated every day.

1) Is a custom trigger the best solution to this problem?

2) How to prepare such a trigger in scala?

Comment: why not use a sliding window with a span of 10 days and slide of 1 days?

Comment: @sinanspd because then i will get aggregate for periods of days 1-10, 2-11, 3-12 ... instead of 1-10, 11-20, 21-30... which doesnt solve my problem.

Comment: Can You elaborate on what You need?  It's not exactly clear from the description.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that but I am trying to understand your reasoning behind this. When you trigger that tumbling window everyday, eventually it will get to a point too far in the future, for which you might not have data and your window will not close. Do you reset the window when you hit 20-30? i.e. ```10-20, 20-30, 0-10, 10-20 ....``` ? We need some examples and more clarity

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60600635/2000823.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [flink count distinct issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60599700/flink-count-distinct-issue)